# Нарушает ли JPA принцип DDD?

Tags: java, ddd

Собственно, в заголовке вопрос. Аннотации JPA привязывают нас к самому JPA. Верно ли это? Или всё таки надо делать свой доменный слой, репозитории и прочие сервисы, а jpa разместить в инфраструктурном слое? Но в jpa свои энтити, сервисы, репозитории, не будет ли дублирования кода?

Comment: Дублирование кода часто бывает после копирования существующего кода, а баги появляются после его модификации.

Comment: Дублирование кода часто бывает после копирования существующего кода, а баги появляются после его модификации.

Comment: Под DDD вы подразумеваете Domain Driven Design или Data Driven Design?

Comment: Domain Driven Design